# Looking for a javascript unit-testing suite to be used with Nashorn's jjs interpreter

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, nashorn

Nashorn's jjs interpreter allows to perform many complex tasks like creating web servers, database operations and swing/javafx interfaces. Most benefits of such approach are the quick experimentations and ability to use any java library you could think of.

I'm using Nashorn in pure javascript mode, ie :

- I'm using exclusively the provided jjs interpreter from Nashorn.
- I'm not calling Nashorn interpreter from a java program
- I'm not using avatarjs or a nodejs equivalent overlay

*All is well*. Yet, I'm unable to make standard javascript unit-testing suites work with Nashorn's jjs.

I've looked at jasmine, qunit, mocha and many others frameworks with no valid result.. I even tried to make java junit work with pure jjs scripts.

Many of these have js test runners I found request running on a web client, and this is out of my scope.

I wish to be able to run a true **agnostic** javascript testsuite with Nashorn jjs interpreter in pure js mode, not in java mode.

Is there such a tool and if so how can it be used with Nashorn's jjs?

---

**Update:**

Following up on Sirko's answer, I managed to mimick the expected behavior with these 2 code snippets (warning: Nashorn's specifics inside)

**qunit-nashorn.js:**

```
load("qunit-1.18.0.js");

with(QUnit) {
  init();
  log(function(d) {
    if (!d.result) {
      var message = d.name + "\tFAIL" + d.source;
      message += " actual: " + d.actual + " <> expected: " + d.expected;
      print(message);
    }
  });
  done(function(d) {
    print("time:\t",d.runtime,"ms");
    print("total:\t",d.total);
    print("passed:\t",d.passed);
    print("failed:\t",d.failed);
  });
}
```

**qunit_poc.js:**

```
load("qunit-nashorn.js");

with(QUnit) {
  test("test1", function(a) { a.equal(true,true); });
  test("test2", function(a) { a.equal(false,true); });
}

QUnit.load();
```

And running these using pure jjs gives the following result:

> > jjs qunit_poc.js

```
test2   FAIL    at <anonymous> (qunit_poc.js:5) actual: false <> expected: true
time:    355 ms
total:   2
passed:  1
failed:  1
```

Comment: In QUnit you can set event listeners for the tests and hence return the results in any form you need/want. It should be possible to get this running in your environment.

Comment: @sirko could you please provide a detailed example of setting up such event listenener? I do not see any result from a simple assertion using qunit-1.18.0.js

Comment: @downvoter: could you please explain why you felt this question is off-topic with regards to testing and programming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an excerpt from some code of mine, which I used a while ago to have QUnit return custom output from the testruns:

```
QUnit.init();

// (failed) tests
QUnit.log( function(details) {} );

// module start
QUnit.moduleStart( function( details ){} );

// module summary
QUnit.moduleDone( function( details ){} );

// test begin
QUnit.testStart( function( details ){} );

// test end
QUnit.testDone( function( details ){} );

// finished all testing
QUnit.done( function(){} );
```

Using those functions/callbacks/event listeners I set up my custom output from the QUnit tests. The actual test were than added like this:

```
// start module
QUnit.module( 'myModuleName' );

// some tests
QUnit.test( 'some test', function( assert ) { } );

// execute
QUnit.load();
```

This code is rather old, so QUnit might be providing an easier way to do this, but this used to work for me.

Comment: ok I figured out most of these by reverse engineering but I was missing QUnit.load()... I need more testing before I marked this as answered. Thanks for the 1st answer

Comment: excellent! I managed to make it work. Bunch of thanks, and of course answer accepted!